# Displaying one image in multiple locations

Tags: javascript, filereader

Disclaimer upfront: I'm still very new to JavaScript. (And to programming in general, for that matter.)

So, I'm trying to create an interface that would display an image in multiple aspect ratios, when cropped by [`object-fit: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit). I'd like to see several aspect ratios side-by-side and be able to test different images as well.

I'm using JavaScript's File API to avoid uploading/downloading. It's also worth noting that I'm doing everything on Google Apps Script so it can be an easily accessible web app.

Right now, I have the `<img>` in a `<div>` so I can use replaceChild. That's the only way I've been able to get it to work. You can see it [here on CodePen](https://codepen.io/xylon3/pen/BYGjyQ). This is the function I've been using:

```
function handleImage(e){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            var placehold = document.getElementById('userImg');
            document.getElementById('userImageDiv').replaceChild(img, placeHold);
        }
        img.id = "userImg";
        img.src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

**What I've tried:**

I tried getting the `img.onload` function to append `img` twice:

```
var placeholdTwo = document.getElementById('imgTwo');
document.getElementById('imageTwoDiv').replaceChild(img, placeholdTwo);
```

But it only displayed in `imgTwo` - I'm guessing because the function only creates one FileReader.

I also tried reading the image in one location, then copying it's src to additional locations, but no luck there:

```
function repeatImg(){
    var repeatImage = document.getElementById('userImg').src;
    document.getElementById('imageOne').src = repeatImage;
    document.getElementById('imageTwo').src = repeatImage;
}
```

Then, I tried making multiples of the whole `handleImage` function and calling them all with an event listener, but that didn't work either.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply wrap the original file object, which is a blob, and set that as source. This way you avoid adding up memory usage and base64 encoding/decoding overheads as with a Data-URL - there's no need to create an intermediate image element either - just update the `src` on the existing ones:

```js
document.querySelector("input").onchange = handleImage;

function handleImage() {
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
  document.getElementById('userImg').src =
  document.getElementById('imageOne').src =
  document.getElementById('imageTwo').src = url;
}
```

```html
<label>Select an image: <input type=file></label>
<img id=userImg>
<img id=imageOne>
<img id=imageTwo>
```

Comment: Fantastic! I feel like I'm learning a new language, and just starting to understand the logic of it. Building vocabulary is the hard part. Thanks for the more efficient solution!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the linked pen, repeatImg does not get called by the userImgDiv change event listener.

Calling repeatImg() at the end of img.onload works for me.

```
img.onload = function(){
            var placeHold = document.getElementById('userImg');
            document.getElementById('userImageDiv').replaceChild(img, placeHold);
            repeatImg();
        }
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/markdon/pen/GQwZRM).

Comment: I could have sworn I tried this a million times, though I was running repeatImg() through a button click. This worked great as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps I'm missing something, but why not just set the image sources in your img.onload method?

```
function handleImage(e){
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event){
      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function(){
          var placehold = document.getElementById('userImg');
          document.getElementById('userImageDiv').replaceChild(img, placeHold);
          document.getElementById('imageOne').src = img.src;
          document.getElementById('imageTwo').src = img.src;
      }
      img.id = "userImg";
      img.src = event.target.result;
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

Comment: You know? I tried something similar, but failed to add .src to img. I was just thinking of img as a file and not as the full markup. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You're only using one Image. I would do something like this instead:

```js
/* external.js */
//<![CDATA[
var doc, bod, M, I, Q, S, old = onload; // for use on other loads
onload = function(){
if(old)old(); // change old var name if using technique on other pages
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
M = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
Q = function(selector, withinElement){
  var w = withinElement || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
S = function(selector, withinElement){
  var w = withinElement || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
I('form').onsubmit = function(){
  return false;
}
// you can put the below code on another page onload if you want
var up = I('upload'), out = I('out'), reader = new FileReader;
up.onchange = function(){
  reader.onload = function(){
    var img0 = M('img'), img1 = M('img');
    img0.src = img1.src = this.result; out.innerHTML = '';
    out.appendChild(img0); out.appendChild(img1);
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
}
}
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
body{
  background:#000; overflow-y:scroll;
}
.main{
  width:940px; background:#ccc; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <form id='form' name='form'>
      <input id='upload' name='upload' type='file' />
    </form>
    <div id='out'></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you playing code golf? why are you naming the functions 'M', 'I', 'Q' and 'S' instead of more readable names like 'makeElement()'  or 'getElement()'?